# How can I only get the first N numbers in a Date column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I want to clean up this date column inside of a csv file using python pandas.

Let's say my code is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['alice','bob','charlie'],
    'date_of_birth': ['10/25/2005 R','10/29/2002','01/01/2001 BD']
})
```

**How can I clean up this mess for thousands of rows?**

I thought of using:

```
df['date of birth'] = df['new date'].str[0,10]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: `df['new date'].str[:10]`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to do:

```
df['new date'] = df['date_of_birth'].apply(lambda d: d[0:10])
```

It just applies the function to take the first 10 characters to each entry.

The answer in the comment section works as well if you flip `new date` for `date_of_birth` and is probably faster:

```
df['new date'] = df['date_of_birth'].str[:10]
```

Comment: yes, but easy to understand. I added a fixed version of your comment as well

Comment: yes, I have to say just copied OP's code without checking

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the dates aren't always the first 10 items in the string (e.g 1/1/2023) you can split it based on the space that comes after the date, then take the date:

```
df['new date'] = df['date_of_birth'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```